Create a trigger for the view. oracle
Create a trigger for the view, which, at the first change (UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT, MERGE) of data in the tables on which the view is based, will add USER and TIME columns to the table being modified with information in the rows being modified about the user and the time of change. In subsequent accesses to tables with already created columns, the trigger must correct the information in the USER and TIME columns. You only need to create a trigger
This is my solution, but when I use UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT on a table, no new columns are added. According to the task, you need to create a trigger for the view, and manipulate the table
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER audit_changes_trg INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON EMP_VIEWDOP5 DECLARE PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION; v_column_exists NUMBER; BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO v_column_exists
FROM user_tab_columns
WHERE table_name = 'EMPLOYEESDOP5'
AND column_name = 'USERAUDIT';

IF v_column_exists = 0 THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEESDOP5 ADD (
        USERaudit VARCHAR2(30),
        TIMEaudit TIMESTAMP)';
END IF;

IF INSERTING THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
    'INSERT INTO EMPLOYEESDOP5 (EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, EMP_SALARY, DEPT_ID, USERaudit, TIMEaudit)
     VALUES (:1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6)'
    USING :NEW.EMP_ID, :NEW.EMP_NAME, :NEW.EMP_SALARY, :NEW.DEPT_ID, USER, SYSTIMESTAMP;
END IF;

IF UPDATING THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
    'UPDATE EMPLOYEESDOP5 
     SET EMP_NAME = :1, 
         EMP_SALARY = :2, 
         DEPT_ID = :3,
         USERaudit = :4,
         TIMEaudit = :5
     WHERE EMP_ID = :6'
    USING :NEW.EMP_NAME, :NEW.EMP_SALARY, :NEW.DEPT_ID, USER, SYSTIMESTAMP, :OLD.EMP_ID;
END IF;

IF DELETING THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
    'DELETE FROM EMPLOYEESDOP5 WHERE EMP_ID = :1'
    USING :OLD.EMP_ID;
END IF;
END;


I've added tags for Oracle and PL/SQL, because from the syntax this looks like an Oracle trigger (written in PL/SQL). If I am wrong, please change the tags. Always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS in order to get appropriate answers.

"at the first change ... of data in the tables on which the view is based" and "when I use ... on a table" don't really make sense; if you're directly manipulating data in the table a trigger on the view won't fire; you would have to manipulate the view (insert into EMP_VIEWDOP5..., not insert into EMPLOYEESDOP5).  A view is just a stored query, so it will reflect changes to data in the table, but won't act on them. The exercise seems badly worded, at best (and this seems like a horrible thing to have to do anyway - modifying table definitions at runtime, forcing dynamic SQL...).


... when I use UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT on a table, no new columns are added.

You didn't explain what that means. Added where? If you checked the view, of course they aren't added because view definition is set before that trigger ran for the first time. But, if you checked the table, audit tables should exist.
Here's a demo based on Scott's sample schema, its emp table.
Test table:
SQL> CREATE TABLE emp_test
  2  AS
  3     SELECT empno,
  4            ename,
  5            job,
  6            sal
  7       FROM emp
  8      WHERE deptno = 10;

Table created.

A view based on that table:
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_emp_test
  2  AS
  3     SELECT * FROM emp_test;

View created.

Trigger; note that it requires commit at the end because it is an autonomous transaction:
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER audit_changes_trg
  2     INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
  3     ON v_emp_test
  4  DECLARE
  5     PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  6     v_column_exists  NUMBER;
  7  BEGIN
  8     SELECT COUNT (*)
  9       INTO v_column_exists
 10       FROM user_Tab_columns
 11      WHERE     table_name = 'EMP_TEST'
 12            AND column_name = 'USERAUDIT';
 13
 14     IF v_column_exists = 0
 15     THEN
 16        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter table emp_test add (useraudit varchar2(30), timeaudit date)';
 17     END IF;
 18
 19     IF INSERTING
 20     THEN
 21        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'insert into emp_test (empno, ename, job, sal, useraudit, timeaudit)
 22      values (:1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6)'
 23           USING :new.empno,
 24                 :new.ename,
 25                 :new.job,
 26                 :new.sal,
 27                 USER,
 28                 SYSDATE;
 29     ELSIF UPDATING
 30     THEN
 31        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'update emp_test set
 32        ename = :1, job = :2, sal = :3, useraudit = :4, timeaudit = :5
 33        where empno = :6'
 34           USING :new.ename,
 35                 :new.job,
 36                 :new.sal,
 37                 USER,
 38                 SYSDATE,
 39                 :new.empno;
 40     ELSIF DELETING
 41     THEN
 42        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'delete from emp_test where empno = :1'
 43           USING :old.empno;
 44     END IF;
 45
 46     COMMIT;
 47  END;
 48  /

Trigger created.

Testing: table contents:
SQL> SELECT * FROM emp_test;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         2450
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT       5000
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           1300

View contents:
SQL> SELECT * FROM v_emp_test;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         2450
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT       5000
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           1300

Let's update the view; trigger should fire and add audit columns to the table (not the view!):
SQL> UPDATE v_emp_test
  2     SET sal = 2000
  3   WHERE job = 'CLERK';

1 row updated.

Table's new contents; as you can see, salary has been raised and new columns have been added:
SQL> SELECT * FROM emp_test;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL USERAUDIT                      TIMEAUDIT
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ------------------------------ -------------------
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         2450
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT       5000
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           2000 SCOTT                          09.10.2024 08:16:31

What about the view? Nothing (apart from the fact that it reflects salary change):
SQL> SELECT * FROM v_emp_test;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         2450
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT       5000
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           2000

If you want to add new columns to the view as well, you'll have to recreate the view:
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_emp_Test
  2  AS
  3     SELECT * FROM emp_test;

View created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM v_emp_test;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL USERAUDIT                      TIMEAUDIT
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ------------------------------ -------------------
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         2450
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT       5000
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           2000 SCOTT                          09.10.2024 08:16:31

SQL>


Thanks for the answer, but the task requires creating a trigger on a view that will track operations in the table and change the table. I got the same as you, when I use operations on the view, everything works as it should.
